# Write to last line of file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna save some string on a file that i called inv.data. Every time i write a special command, I want to save a string in the file. The string should be at the last line in the file all times.
I read something about append, so I tried to do something like this:

```
#Open and close the inventroy file
fileOpen = open('inv.data', 'a')
fileOpen.write(argOne)
fileOpen.close()

fileOpen = open('inv.data', 'r')
savedData = fileOpen.read().splitlines()
fileOpen.close()
```

This works fine the first time I want to add something during runtime, but when I try to add the second string it looks something like this:

```
sword
axe
shield
bow
flower
monsterLol
```

Where monster was the first add, and Lol was the second thing I added.
What am I missing? Do I need to specify that it should go to a new line each time or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New line is not getting added and hence the next entry is appended in the same line. You ca rectify this as follows:

```
fileOpen.write(argOne + '\n')
```

This way you don't have to modify the way you input your arguments.